# How to store all values from 100 to "User Input" in an array

Tags: java, arrays, palindrome

When I'm done with this program it is suppose to display all palindromes and all prime palindromes that are greater than 100 and less than the number input by the user.  As I'm going along in this assignment, I'm getting confused on how to store those values into the array that I have created "char[] charUser"

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
    Scanner promptUser = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter an Integer greater than 100: ");
    Integer userInt = new Integer(promptUser.nextInt());
    String userString = userInt.toString();
    char[] charUser = userString.toCharArray();

    if (userInt <= 100)
    {    
        System.out.print("That integer is not greater than 100,"
                        + " restart program and try again!");
    }

    char[] resultArray = reverseArray(charUser);
    for(int i = 0; i < resultArray.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(resultArray[i]);
        }
}

/**Takes the integer provided by the user and turns it into a string 
 * then takes that string and puts it into a char[], then there is a for loop 
 * to reverse that array.
 * @param charUser array used to store the reversed string.
 * @revArray char array used to store data from charChange array.
 * @return returns charChange now with the reversed string.
 */
public static char[] reverseArray(char[] charUser)
{
    char[] revArray = new char[charUser.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < revArray.length; i++)
    {
        revArray[i] = charUser[charUser.length - 1 - i];
    }

    return revArray;    
}

/** Takes the original array charUser before being reversed and 
 * compares it with the reversed array resultArray to determine if they
 * are equal.
 * @param charUser original array created from the user input.
 * @param resultArray the reversed array of charUser.
 * @return returns the answer to boolean isPalindrome, whether or not the 
 * two arrays are equal.
 */
public static boolean arraysAreEqual(char[] charUser, char[] resultArray) 
{
   char[] isPal1 = new char[charUser.length];
   char[] isPal2 = new char[resultArray.length];
   boolean isPalindrome = false;

   if(isPal1[isPal1.length] == isPal2[isPal2.length])
   {
       isPalindrome = true;
   }

   return isPalindrome;
} 

public static boolean isPrime(int userInt)
{
    int intUser = userInt;
    boolean checkPrime = true;

    for(int i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(intUser); i++)
    {
        if(intUser % i == 0)
        return false;
    }

    return checkPrime;
}

/*public void printArray(char[] resultArray)
{

}*/
```

}

Comment: To be clear, it is only storing the user input, and not all values between 100 and the user input (obviously I haven't told it to yet, because I don't know how :0)).

Comment: Why not just store them as integers? You can write a function that can determine if an integer is a palindrome too

Comment: Why do u ask the user to restart the program if the  `userInt`is > `100` , you can just prompt the user to input a new `int`

Comment: nullPointer, the assignment requires us to change it to a string, and then to a char[], is there a way to then convert it back to an integer?  This is my first class ever in Java, so I am very green.

Comment: Sybren, the input has to be greater than 100, I really didn't word the prompt that way for any particular reason, I guess I could change it to having them just input another number.

Comment: If the assignment absolutely requires you to convert to a char[], then you could store it in an arraylist as suggested by the answers below. To convert a char[] (called charArray, for example) to an integer, you can do the following: String numStr = new String(charArray); Integer num = Integer.parseInt(numStr);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an `array`, you need to know exactly the length of the `array` (how many elements you want that array to contain) using this line:

```
int[] palindrome = new int[x]; //x being the length of the array
```

However if you need to add your new found palindromes to an `array` in a dynamic fashion (on the fly) you need to use the `Arraylist` class.

An Arraylist would be initialized like this:

```
Arraylist<Integer> palindromes = new Arraylist<Integer>();
```

ANd then elements can be added whenever you find a new plalindrome with the `add` method of the Arraylist `class`:

```
palindromes.add(x); //x being the number to add to the list
```

You should take a look at Oracle's documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for more info on `Arraylist` and it's many `methods`
Hope this helps

**EDIT**

To answer your question you need to rethink this method completely:

```
public static boolean arraysAreEqual(char[] charUser, char[]      resultArray) 
{
   char[] isPal1 = new char[charUser.length];
   char[] isPal2 = new char[resultArray.length];
   boolean isPalindrome = false;

   if(isPal1[isPal1.length] == isPal2[isPal2.length])
   {
       isPalindrome = true;
   }

   return isPalindrome;
}
```

1. If you want to create a new char array (as a copy of the one passed as a parameter) you can't do it the way you did it. Altought you wouldn't even need to create a new array, you could just used the one passed as a parameter.
2. Next point if you want to compare the `char array` with it's opposite `array`, you need to `loop` and check elements by elements. If you convert them to `int` you can just check easily if they are equal:

   ```
   if (number == oppositeNumber){
       //it is a palindrome
       //Therefor return true
   }
   return false; (if it isn't a palindrome return false)
   ```

**How to cast char array to int**

If you want to convert your `char array` to an `int` you need to do these simple steps:

1. Cast `char array` to `String`
2. Cast `String` to int

Like this examples shows:

```
char[] nums = {'1','2','2','1'};
String str = String.valueOf(nums);
int number = Integer.parseInt(str);
System.out.println(number);
```

Comment: Is there any way in its current form that something could be modified, or must it be an ArrayList?

Comment: You're welcome, you can also help the community and checkmark an answer to show the question as been resolve if you believe it helped you with your question